# Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that ∃x, y ∈ R,(x < y ∧ f(x) = f(y))

Tags: calculus

Let f : R → R be a continuous function. Suppose that

∃a, b ∈ R,(a < b ∧ f(a) < f(b))

and

∃c, d ∈ R,(c < d ∧ f(c) > f(d))

Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that

∃x, y ∈ R,(x < y ∧ f(x) = f(y))

Hint: Construct a continuous function H(t) with the property that H(0) = f(b)−f(a)
and 
H(1) = f(d) − f(c). Then use the Intermediate Value Theorem on H(t) over the
interval [0, 1].

Answer (score 1):

$H(t)=f((1-t)b+td)-f((1-t)a+tc)$.

Comment: Caveat for the OP: this is not a complete answer. However, having in mind that they just posted the question without providing any context - I think this is fair enough! What's left for the OP to do is to prove that the criteria are met for the Intermediate Value Theorem, to propose what $x$ and $y$ may be, and to prove that $x\lt y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: I think the problem faced by OP was in guessing what H should be. I am pretty sure that he can complete the argument.